# Как подключить свои стили Laravel Vue js?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Делаю сайт, решил выучить Vue.js совместно с Laravel, подскажите как подключить свои стили, совместно с стандартными bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Способов полно)

1. в шаблоне blade, через стандартный
2. в `app.js` через `require()`
3. в `_variables.scss` иди `app.scss`
4. Писать стили в самих компонентах Vue. Что в случае работы с данным фреймворков самое правильное. Пример:

```
<template>
<!-- тут будет сам компонент -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "Example"
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
//Ваши стиль
//если указано scoped - стили будут применяться ТОЛЬКО для данного компонента
// в lang можно указывать синтаксис через который пишете. Если не указывать вообще - будет CSS
// для scss или sass небходимо подключать sass-loader и тд 
</style>
```